# Xampp 1.8.3.3 with phpmyadmin 4.1.8 phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

and installed the xampp phpmyadmin and when I entered the following jump

The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here.

and click show and here is errors

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
Configurable menus: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ...     not OK [ Documentation ]
Hide/show navigation items: Disabled

How can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Run the following query in the **phpmyadmin** database:

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_users` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`usergroup`)
) 
  COMMENT='Users and their assignments to user groups'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_usergroups` (
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)
) 
  COMMENT='User groups with configured menu items'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_navigationhiding` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
) 
  COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

---

Then, add the following lines into your **config.inc.php** file:

---

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
```

---

Then, log out of phyMyAdmin and log back in.

**NOTE:** You may also need to create a 'pma' user and grant all permissions on the 'phpmyadmin' database.

Comment: I've also had this issue and this does not work.  Another solution advised PHP was expecting double-underscores in the tables, tried that, still doesn't work.  Very frustrating!

Comment: What part of it doesn't work for you? I have used this method on multiple installs, and it works every time for me. Can you post the message(s) you get when you try it?

Comment: On HOME page, i get [The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. To find out why click here]... If I click it, it tells me: [$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Configurable menus: Disabled
 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ...  not OK [ Documentation ]
Hide/show navigation items: Disabled]

Comment: When you ran the query above, did it create the tables for you under the phpmyadmin database?

Comment: it didn't work for me, ran the query, changed the config.inc.php file, cleaned cache and coookies, and still nothing changed. :(, on a mac with a myphpAdmin 4.2.11 from  xampp.  and i already have a pma user.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_users` (
`username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`usergroup`)
)
COMMENT='Users and their assignments to user groups'
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_usergroups` (
`usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`allowed` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)
)
COMMENT='User groups with configured menu items'
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_navigationhiding` (
`username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`item_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`item_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
`table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree'
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).